# Display the time left of a given time

Tags: javascript, html, css, ecmascript-6, dom

### Context

This software is a countdown/visual timer. It was initially developed to display the time left before the end of an exam.

---

### Question

My JavaScript is working but when I want to validate it by some code quality tool it keeps throwing me this error: `SyntaxError: Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode.`

If any of you can improve this code and help me to improve it(even the design), I would be very grateful.

Here's the code:

```js
'use strict'
 
const load = () => {
    const data = {}
 
    init(data)
 
    setInterval(() => {
        update(data)
        render(data)
    }, 100)
 
    document.querySelector('#start').onclick = event => {
        start(data)
    }
 
    document.querySelector('#reset').onclick = event => {
        reset(data)
    }
 
    document.querySelector('#license').onclick = showLicense
}
 
const init = data => {
    data.canvas = document.querySelector('#countdown')
    data.ctx = data.canvas.getContext('2d')
 
    data.endTime = Date.now()
    data.start = false
    data.reset = false
 
    data.canvas.width = data.canvas.height = 500
}
 
const update = data => {
    if (data.start || data.reset) {
        data.startAngle = timeToAngle(data.endTime)
        data.reset = false
    }
    if (data.start) {
        let difference = Math.abs(Math.floor((data.endTime - Date.now()) / 1000))
        let seconds = pad(difference % 60, '00')
        difference = Math.floor(difference / 60)
        let minutes = pad(difference % 60, '00')
        difference = Math.floor(difference / 60)
        let hours = difference
 
        if (data.endTime < Date.now()) {
            if (hours != 0) {
                hours = -hours
            } else if (minutes != 0) {
                minutes = -minutes
            } else {
                seconds = -seconds
            }
        }
 
        document.querySelector('#hours').value = hours
        document.querySelector('#minutes').value = minutes
        document.querySelector('#seconds').value = seconds
    }
}
 
const render = data => {
    const {
        canvas,
        ctx,
        startAngle,
        start
    } = data
 
    ctx.fillStyle = '#fff'
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
 
    let angle = Math.abs(startAngle)
 
    ctx.save()
 
    if (startAngle > 0) {
        ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)
        ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2)
        ctx.scale(1, -1)
        ctx.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2)
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)'
    } else {
        ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)
        ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2)
        ctx.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2)
        ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)'
    }
 
    while (angle > 2 * Math.PI) {
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.width / 2, canvas.width / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
        ctx.fill()
 
        angle -= 2 * Math.PI
    }
 
    ctx.beginPath()
    ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.width / 2, canvas.width / 2, 0, angle)
    ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2)
    ctx.fill()
 
    ctx.restore()
}
 
const start = data => {
    const button = document.querySelector('#start')
    if (data.start) {
        button.innerText = 'Start'
    } else {
        let hours = document.querySelector('#hours').value
        let minutes = document.querySelector('#minutes').value
        let seconds = document.querySelector('#seconds').value
        if (hours.trim() == '') hours = 0
        if (minutes.trim() == '') minutes = 0
        if (seconds.trim() == '') seconds = 0
 
        let sign
        if (hours != 0) {
            sign = hours < 0 ? -1 : 1
        } else if (minutes != 0) {
            sign = minutes < 0 ? -1 : 1
        } else {
            sign = seconds < 0 ? -1 : 1
        }
 
        minutes = sign * Math.abs(minutes)
        seconds = sign * Math.abs(seconds)
 
        data.endTime = Date.now() + 3600000 * hours + 60000 * minutes + 1000 * seconds
 
        button.innerText = 'Pause'
    }
    data.start ^= true
}
 
const reset = data => {
    data.endTime = Date.now()
    data.start = false
    document.querySelector('#hours').value = ''
    document.querySelector('#minutes').value = ''
    document.querySelector('#seconds').value = ''
    document.querySelector('#start').innerText = 'Start'
    data.reset = true
}
 
const showLicense = () => {
    const mask = document.createElement('div')
    mask.style = 'position:fixed;left:0;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);z-index:1;'
    mask.onclick = () => {
        document.body.removeChild(mask)
        document.body.removeChild(message)
    }
    document.body.appendChild(mask)
 
    const message = document.createElement('div')
    message.style = 'position:fixed;left:50%;top:50%;transform:translate(-50%, -50%);z-index:2;background:#fff;padding:10px;border-radius:10px;overflow:auto;max-width:600px;max-height:500px;'
    message.innerText = 'License unavailable, please report as a bug.'
    message.onclick = () => {
        document.body.removeChild(mask)
        document.body.removeChild(message)
    }
 
    const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest()
    ajax.open('GET', 'LICENSE')
    ajax.onreadystatechange = () => {
        console.log('AJAX');
        message.innerText = ajax.responseText
    }
    ajax.send()
    document.body.append(message)
}
 
const timeToAngle = endTime => {
    const difference = endTime - Date.now()
    return difference / 3600000 * 2 * Math.PI
}
 
const pad = (value, format) => (format + value).slice(-format.length)
 
load()
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background: #eee;
    margin: 0;
}

main {
    background: #fff;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    align-items: center;
}

h1 {
    text-align: center;
}

menu {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    width: 500px;
    padding: 0;
}

#hours, #minutes, #seconds {
    width: 30px;
    text-align: center;
}

footer {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: auto;
    background: #ddd;
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

footer a {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

footer a:hover {
    background: #888;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Countdown</title>
    <script src="countdown.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
    <main>
        <h1 contenteditable>Countdown</h1>
        <canvas id="countdown"></canvas>
        <menu>
            <button id="reset">Reset</button>
            <div class="group">
                <input id="hours" placeholder="HH" autofocus>:<input id="minutes" placeholder="MM">:<input id="seconds" placeholder="SS">
            </div>
            <button id="start">Start</button>
        </menu>
    </main>
    <footer>
        <a href="https://github.com/SteeveDroz/countdown">Find the project on GitHub</a>
        <a href="https://github.com/SteeveDroz/countdown/issues">Report bugs</a>
        <a id="license">MIT license</a>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're using a browser version that doesn't support `const` when in strict mode, most likely a Safari version prior to 10. Simple fix is to just use `var` or transpile with babel. See [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45288836/1765851). I'd say this question is also better placed over at the Stack Overflow site.

Comment: I've edited the title and I don't know why it can't pass jslint.com or other validators will keep throwing the same error(I'm pretty lost.) @Svenskunganka

Comment: jslint.com does not support latest JavaScript syntax - it's a pretty outdated site. Try ESLint instead.

Answer (score 2):

You're passing your app state as the parameter `data` to almost all the functions.

This suggests you're better off combining these functions into a class, where you could assign these values to `this` which would be automatically accessible from all methods in class.

Alternatively, if this all is a tiny app, you could just use global variables, which too would be accessible from all functions.

Answer (score 1):

#### Review points

- Fetching DOM elements is not cheap, so cache those in a variable (perhaps in `data`) instead of accessing them each time.
- When fetching DOM elements by id attribute, use `document.getElementById()` instead of `document.querySelector('#')` refer to answers to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26848289/1575353) and [the relevant jsPerf test](https://jsperf.com/getelementbyid-vs-queryselector)
- An event delegate can reduce the number of click handlers needed - the example snippet below uses [Function.bind()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to create [partially applied functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Partially_applied_functions) for a simple event delegate - if you didn't use an event delegate, the click handlers like:

  > ```
  > document.querySelector('#start').onclick = event => {
  >     start(data)
  > }
  > ```

  Could be simplified like this:

  ```
  document.querySelector('#start').onclick = start.bind(null, data)
  ```
- Unless you fully understand the ways [Automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion) can be broken by certain statements, add semi-colons to terminate the lines.
- The AJAX statechange handler (i.e. registered via `onreadystatechange`) doesn't check the [`readyState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/readyState) and [`status`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status) properties of the request, and thus the `innerText` property of `message` will likely be updated before desired (e.g. during request open, transmission, loading, etc.)

#### Rewrite

Below is what one could do with the advice above.

```js
'use strict'

const load = () => {
  const data = {};

  init(data);

  setInterval(() => {
    update(data);
    render(data);
  }, 100);
  const mapping = {
    "start": start.bind(null, data),
    "reset": reset.bind(null, data),
    "license": showLicense
  };
  const clickHandler = event => event.target.id in mapping && mapping[event.target.id]();
  document.body.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
}

const init = data => {
  data.canvas = document.getElementById('countdown');
  data.ctx = data.canvas.getContext('2d');

  data.endTime = Date.now();
  data.start = false;
  data.reset = false;

  data.canvas.width = data.canvas.height = 500;

  const inputs = ['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds'];
  inputs.forEach(inputName => data[inputName + 'Input'] = document.getElementById(inputName));
  data.startButton = document.getElementById('start');
}

const update = data => {
  if (data.start || data.reset) {
    data.startAngle = timeToAngle(data.endTime);
    data.reset = false;
  }
  if (data.start) {
    let difference = Math.abs(Math.floor((data.endTime - Date.now()) / 1000));
    let seconds = pad(difference % 60, '00');
    difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);
    let minutes = pad(difference % 60, '00');
    difference = Math.floor(difference / 60);
    let hours = difference;

    if (data.endTime < Date.now()) {
      if (hours != 0) {
        hours = -hours;
      } else if (minutes != 0) {
        minutes = -minutes;
      } else {
        seconds = -seconds;
      }
    }

    data.hoursInput.value = hours;
    data.minutesInput.value = minutes;
    data.secondsInput.value = seconds;
  }
}

const render = data => {
  const {
    canvas,
    ctx,
    startAngle,
    start
  } = data;

  ctx.fillStyle = '#fff';
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  let angle = Math.abs(startAngle);

  ctx.save();

  if (startAngle > 0) {
    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
    ctx.scale(1, -1);
    ctx.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.5)';
  } else {
    ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.rotate(-Math.PI / 2);
    ctx.translate(-canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  }

  while (angle > 2 * Math.PI) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.width / 2, canvas.width / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();

    angle -= 2 * Math.PI;
  }

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.width / 2, canvas.width / 2, 0, angle);
  ctx.lineTo(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
  ctx.fill();

  ctx.restore();
}

const start = data => {
  if (data.start) {
    data.startButton.innerText = 'Start';
  } else {
    let hours = data.hoursInput.value;
    let minutes = data.minutesInput.value;
    let seconds = data.secondsInput.value;
    if (hours.trim() == '') hours = 0;
    if (minutes.trim() == '') minutes = 0;
    if (seconds.trim() == '') seconds = 0;

    let sign;
    if (hours != 0) {
      sign = hours < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    } else if (minutes != 0) {
      sign = minutes < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    } else {
      sign = seconds < 0 ? -1 : 1;
    }

    minutes = sign * Math.abs(minutes);
    seconds = sign * Math.abs(seconds);

    data.endTime = Date.now() + 3600000 * hours + 60000 * minutes + 1000 * seconds;

    data.startButton.innerText = 'Pause';
  }
  data.start ^= true;
}

const reset = data => {
  data.endTime = Date.now();
  data.start = false;
  data.hoursInput.value = '';
  data.minutesInput.value = '';
  data.secondsInput.value = '';
  data.startButton.innerText = 'Start';
  data.reset = true;
}

const showLicense = () => {
  const mask = document.createElement('div');
  mask.id = 'mask';
  mask.onclick = () => {
    document.body.removeChild(mask);
    document.body.removeChild(message);
  }
  document.body.appendChild(mask);

  const message = document.createElement('div');
  message.id = 'messageContainer';
  message.innerText = 'License unavailable, please report as a bug.';
  message.onclick = () => {
    document.body.removeChild(mask);
    document.body.removeChild(message);
  }

  const ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
  ajax.open('GET', '/');
  ajax.onreadystatechange = () => {
    //check state, this doesn't make sense here in this snippet
    if (ajax.readyState === 4 && ajax.status === 200) {
      //message.innerText = ajax.responseText
    }
  };
  ajax.send();
  document.body.append(message);
}

const timeToAngle = endTime => {
  const difference = endTime - Date.now();
  return difference / 3600000 * 2 * Math.PI;
}

const pad = (value, format) => (format + value).slice(-format.length);

load();
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  background: #fff;
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  align-items: center;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 500px;
  padding: 0;
}

#hours,
#minutes,
#seconds {
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

footer {
  max-width: 700px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

footer a {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

footer a:hover {
  background: #888;
  color: #fff;
}

#mask {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  z-index: 1;
}

#messageContainer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 600px;
  max-height: 500px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <h1 contenteditable>Countdown</h1>
  <canvas id="countdown"></canvas>
  <menu>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    <div class="group">
      <input id="hours" placeholder="HH" autofocus>:<input id="minutes" placeholder="MM">:<input id="seconds" placeholder="SS">
    </div>
    <button id="start">Start</button>
  </menu>
</main>
<footer>
  <a href="https://github.com/SteeveDroz/countdown">Find the project on GitHub</a>
  <a href="https://github.com/SteeveDroz/countdown/issues">Report bugs</a>
  <a id="license">MIT license</a>
</footer>
```